# How to test if an element is present using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to test if an element is present on a webpage. When the element is present, it works just fine. When the element is not present, test run is paused     at this line

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(elb).size() > 0; // first way
```

or

```
`boolean eleSelected= driver.findElement(elb).isDisplayed();` // second way
```

// test if element is present

```
By elb = By.className("item-overview__online-listing");
System.out.println("one");
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(elb).size() > 0;
System.out.println("text 3" + isPresent);
```

I also do not get any error. I waited about 3 minutes. Script's status is running without doing anything. I was never got to the last line. How can I test if an element is present on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and it will work

```
List <WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("<<xpath of the element>>"));
if (allElements.size() == 0) {

System.out.Println("Elements are not present");

} else {

System.out.Println("Elements are present");
// do something with element present...
...
...
}
```

The above lines of code will not stop your execution and also will ensure to just check for the elements presence and move ahead.

Comment: It did not work for me. If element is present, it works just fine. If element is not present, it hangs without presenting any error.